# Getting multiple values from checked checkboxes Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there would be away to get the values of checked checkboxes and than use the values in the filter function in my DeleteObject function.

```
<div style="text-align:center" class="list">
  <small>Walls:</small><input id="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Wall">
  <small>Doors:</small><input id="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Door">
  <small>Traps:</small><input id="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="SlowTrap"><br>
  <small>Mines:</small><input id="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="GoldMine">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function DeleteObject() {
  var b = Game.currentGame.ui.buildings;
  Object.keys(b).filter(function(e) {

    return CheckBoxValuesHere == b[e].type;

  }).forEach(function(i) {
    Game.currentGame.network.sendRpc({
      name: "DeleteObject",
      uid: b[i].uid
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID in a single document is **invalid HTML**. Consider fixing that first

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID is INVALID. You should use the `name` property instead.

Comment: `cblist = getElementsByName('boxes-shared-name');` will get you the elements to loop through, once you change id= to name=.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `id's` should be unique. To get the values of checked checkboxes, add `change` event to the input with type `checkbox` and then grab input with checked checkboxes.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener('change', function() {
            const values = [...document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')].map(input => input.value);
            console.log(values);
        });
    });
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center" class="list">
    <small>Walls:</small><input id="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Wall">
    <small>Doors:</small><input id="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Door">
    <small>Traps:</small><input id="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="SlowTrap"><br>
    <small>Mines:</small><input id="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="GoldMine">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getItemsToDelete() {
  // get a nodeList of all selected elements,
  // convert it to an array and return an
  // array of the values.
  return Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(
      'input[name=deleteCheckbox]:checked'
    )
  ).map( item => item.value );
}
console.log(getItemsToDelete());
```

```html
<ul style="list-style:none">
  <li><input name="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Wall"><small>Walls</small></li>
  <li><input name="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Door" checked><small>Doors</small></li>
  <li><input name="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="SlowTrap"><small>Traps</small></li>
  <li><input name="deleteCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="GoldMine"><small>Mines</small></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add unique names or IDs to each checkbox and assign them listeners to `click` event (in JS code) or directly in HTML. Then in JS refer to checkbox value with `document.getElementById(<ID>).value`.